# Use iTunes credit to purchase items

Tags: itunes, applications, apple-store

I have redeemed several hundred dollars of iTunes money to my Apple account. Is there any any app(s) in the store that allow you to pay for something (at a high price of course, due to Apple’s fees) that can be shipped to your door (and potentially re-sold) with iTunes credit?

Is this allowed in Apple’s App Store Terms of Services, or are all In-App Purchases intended to cover some digital artefacts?

If so, do apps allow you to buy currency which is in turn redeemable for something tangible or exchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes Store credit can be used only for purchasing content sold on the App Store/iTunes Store, or for upgrading iCloud storage. Official instructions can be found here:

- [Redeem App Store & iTunes Gift Cards, Apple Music Gift Cards, and content codes](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201209)

Selling of physical goods is not permitted on the App Store as per the App Store Review Guidelines. Refer specifically to the [Business section](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#goods-and-services) of the document:

> **3.1.5 (a) Goods and Services Outside of the App:** If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Didn't know about iCloud storage. Is it a subscription or one-time payment?

Comment: @JudsonHudson It's a monthly subscription. You can find more details here: [iCloud storage plans and pricing](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201238).